# How to count to 100 in a different base than 10 (java program)

Tags: java, int, calculator, radix

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem5 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Base Calculator");
    System.out.println("Input a number greater than 0 and less than 10 to use as your base");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Base: ");
    //menu
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int base = 0;
    int basenumber[];
    basenumber = new int[1000001];
    base = input.nextInt();
    int remainder, tens;

    if (base <= 0 || base >=10) { //only working with this parameter
        System.out.println("This calculator does not work with bases that are less than 1 or bases that are greater than 9. Please re-run the program.");
        return;
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("(This means a base " + base + " calculator. Hence, the allowed values corresponding to base 10 values of 0 through 102 would be: ");
        for(int i = 0; i<=101; i++) { //a sample of what i am getting when a base is inputed;notice how when the number gets to 40 base 4, it does not go automatically to 100
            if(i < base){
                basenumber[i] = i;
                System.out.print(basenumber[i] + ", ");
            }
            if (i >= base && i < 101){
                tens = (i / base) * 10;
                remainder = i % base;
                basenumber[i] = tens + remainder;
                System.out.print(basenumber[i] + ", ");
            }
            if (i >= base && i == 101){
                tens = (i / base) * 10;
                remainder = i % base;
                basenumber[i] = tens + remainder;
                System.out.println(basenumber[i] + ")");
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
        //How could I change the above code to make it such that when four 4's show up in the base 4 fours spot (base 10 tens spot), it sees that as one 16 and moves it to the base 4 sixteens spot (base 10 hundreds spot)?
    }
}
}
```

output

Base Calculator
Input a number greater than 0 and less than 10 to use as your base

---

Base: 
4
(This means a base 4 calculator. Hence, the allowed values corresponding to base 10 values of 0 through 102 would be: 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 30, 31, 32, 33, 40, 41, 42, 43, 50, 51, 52, 53, 60, 61, 62, 63, 70, 71, 72, 73, 80, 81, 82, 83, 90, 91, 92, 93, 100, 101, 102, 103, 110, 111, 112, 113, 120, 121, 122, 123, 130, 131, 132, 133, 140, 141, 142, 143, 150, 151, 152, 153, 160, 161, 162, 163, 170, 171, 172, 173, 180, 181, 182, 183, 190, 191, 192, 193, 200, 201, 202, 203, 210, 211, 212, 213, 220, 221, 222, 223, 230, 231, 232, 233, 240, 241, 242, 243, 250, 251

The output expected are:
0,1,2,3,10,......,33,100,101,102,103,110 (Base 4)

How can I modify the code above to produce the expected output?

Comment: What is your problem? Error? Unexpected output?

Comment: you just gave us code. Tell what's the problem? What's wrong with output?

Comment: Your expected output goes wrong after 33 -- that is not the expected output of a base 4 sequence.  Remember that base X means that there is no single character that represents X.  X=10.  True for base 2, and base 102.

Comment: Im sorry I did not make it clear but the question was commented in the code:How could I change the above code to make it such that when four 4's show up in the base 4 fours spot (base 10 tens spot), it sees that as one 16 and moves it to the base 4 sixteens spot (base 10 hundreds spot)?

Answer (score 2):

Never reinvent the wheel if you don't have to...

```
for (int i=0; i<101; i++)
{
      System.out.print(Integer.toString(i, base));
      if (i!=100)
      {
        System.out.print(", ");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is an example if you decided not to use *Integer.toString(value, base)*:

```
public class Problem5 {

    public static int convertToBaseNumber(int base10num, int base){
       int highestBase = (int) Math.floor(Math.log(base10num)/Math.log(base));
       int currentBase = highestBase;
       int remainder = base10num;
       int output = 0;
       while(currentBase >= 0){

            int divisor = (int) Math.pow(base,currentBase);

            int num = ((int) Math.floor(remainder/divisor));
            output = output + (int)(num * Math.pow(10,currentBase));

            remainder = remainder%divisor;

            currentBase--;
       }

       return output;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Base Calculator");
        System.out.println("Input a number greater than 0 and less than 10 to use as your base");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Base: ");
        //menu
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int base = input.nextInt();

        if (base <= 0 || base >=10) { 
            System.out.println("This calculator does not work with bases that are less than 1 or bases that are greater than 9. Please re-run the program.");
            return;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("(This means a base " + base + " calculator. Hence, the allowed values corresponding to base 10 values of 0 through 102 would be: ");
            for(int i = 0; i <= 102; i++) {
                System.out.print(Problem5.convertToBaseNumber(i, base) + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```